# After you create a class in C#, what must you do before you can use it in your code?

Tags: c#

After you create a class in C#, what must you do before you can use it in your code?

Comment: Emmm... nothing? Sorry I don't understand your question. And what you mean under _"use"_?

Comment: Could you, please, provide your code and show the place in it where you have troubles?

Comment: you can not use class directly unless it is static. You must create an instance of that class in order to use the class. Class is more like blueprint of an object. use new keyword to create an object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the object if you wanted to use instance members of a class.

[new operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator)

```
Class1 obj  = new Class1();
obj.Yehaa();
```

You should also probably take a walk around

- [Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)
- [Objects (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects)
- [Structs (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs)